# ServerIron: How do I configure a real server to be in 3 VIPs at the same time?

Tags: load-balancing, foundry

I'm forced to work on an old piece of hardware: Foundry ServerIron 450

I have a host that needs to be in 3 VIPs at the same time: 10.1.1.21:3333 aka (host-a:3333)

The problem I'm having is that when I add the host to the last of three VIPs, it shows as "Active-Disabled" in the other two?

I would really like a sample configuration so that this real-server can be "Active-Active" in all three VIPs simultaneously.